# Bitwise - bitCount's formula meaning?

Tags: math, bitwise-operators, bitcount

here is the copy of the code from Integer.bitCount(int i)

I understand all the operators but don't understand how those magic numbers can find out the count! can anyone explain that to me? I can see the pattern (1,2,4,8,16 & 0x5,0x3,0x0f).

```java
        public static int bitCount(int i) {
            // HD, Figure 5-2
            i = i - ((i >>> 1) & 0x55555555);
            i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >>> 2) & 0x33333333);
            i = (i + (i >>> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f;
            i = i + (i >>> 8);
            i = i + (i >>> 16);
            return i & 0x3f;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex c code, I need any one to explain how it is work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841995/complex-c-code-i-need-any-one-to-explain-how-it-is-work)

Comment: @PaulR have you actually read the other post? where does it actually explain the formula / algorithm? plus the other post is in C and with different formula too! how can that be duplicate?

Comment: The answer links to [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel), which explains this and other parallel bit counting methods. The language is pretty much irrelevant as Java and the wider family of C-based languages all share the same/similar bitwise operators and syntax. Note also that there are numerous other duplicates of this question - it was hard to pick just one, and I may not have chosen the best one. There's also a very good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/253056

Comment: I'd rather not close a question which looks valid as a duplicate of a closed question. The suggested duplicate uses a slightly different method (towards the end) and has a less useful title as well. I'd say let's keep this question here. Please consider this before (or instead of) voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

OK, your code is for 32 bit integers, but let's figure out the first step for 16 bit since the alphabet doesn't have 32 letters. Assume the binary form of your input (with byte boundaries indicated by spaces) is

```
i                  = ABCDEFGH IJKLMNOP
i >>> 1            = 0ABCDEFG HIJKLMNO
(i >>> 1) & 0x5555 = 0A0C0E0G 0I0K0M0O
```

So the first two bits of the right hand side in the first assignment are `(AB - 0A)`. Try the combinations:

```
A  B  AB-0A
0  0  00-00 = 00
1  0  10-01 = 01
0  1  01-00 = 01
1  1  11-01 = 10
```

So the first two bits of that result give you the *count* of bits in the first two bits of the input. The same holds for all the other groups of two bits.

Now you do the same thing again. This time we'll consider input in base 4, so two bits form a digit of the notation below, and we can use full 32 bits.

```
i                      = ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP
i & 0x33333333         = 0B0D 0F0H 0J0L 0N0P
i >>> 2                = 0ABC DEFG HIJK LMNO
(i >>> 2) & 0x33333333 = 0A0C 0E0G 0I0K 0M0O
```

So the first four bits of the result are `(0A + 0B) = A + B`, and the same holds for any other group of four bits. So at that point, every group of four bits contains the bit count of these four bits in the original input.

Using base 16, the next step is

```
i                            = AB CD EF GH
i >>> 4                      = 0A BC DE FG
i + (i >>> 4)                = A(A+B) (B+C)(C+D) (D+E)(E+F) (F+G)(G+H)
(i + (i >>> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f = 0(A+B) 0(C+D) 0(E+F) 0(G+H)
```

This works because the bit count in each four-bit-group will always be less than four, so adding two such counts can be represented in four bits without overflow. Therefore the addition will not have any overflow from one four-bit base-16 digit to another. At this point, you have each byte containing the bit count for that byte of the input. [Other algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/1468366) may contine from there using clever multiplication, but the code you quoted sticks to addition for the next steps as well.

```
i                           = A B C D
i >>> 8                     = 0 A B C
i2 = i + (i >>> 8)          = A (A+B) (B+C) (C+D)
i2 >>> 16                   = 0 0 A (A+B)
i3 = i2 + (i2 >>> 1         = A (A+B) (A+B+C) (A+B+C+D)
i3 & 0x3f                   = 0 0 0 (A+B+C+D)
```

Again this makes use of the fact that there is no overflow between digits.